# How to convert timestamp into date using Aggregation Framework in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregate

In mongo shell I have the following code:

```
 date:{$dateToString:{format:"%Y-%m-%d",date:{"$add":[new Date(0),"$ts"]}}}
```

How can I convert it into java? Especially, I don't know how to express the `new Date(0)`.
Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$ts is the total seconds or milliseconds since the standard time of 1970-01-01 00:00:00. So it is a known variable. I don't think you want to calculate its value. Because $ts is just the value you should pass into date. So your code may look like this below:

```
date:{$dateToString:{format:"%Y-%m-%d",date:"$ts"}}
```